# Converting ISO Date String to Jdatechooser date in java

Tags: java, mongodb, jdatechooser

I am using java with MongoDB to store some info including DATE using jdatechooser and I am trying to set the date in another page from the Data base.

When I look in the Db shell i find the date in this format(2019-08-04T17:40:04.022Z) ... I retrieve the DBObject and Set toString() then Print it to find it (Sun Aug 04 19:40:04 EET 2019).

I tested so many codes even from other answers but it seems to be all wrong formats for the date formatter.

However I always get this error :

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Aug 04 19:40:04 EET 2019"

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyy");
Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);
System.out.println(date); //Prints Tue Oct 15 10:20:56 SGT 2015
jDateChooser1.setDate(date1);
```

Examples of the formats I used

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
EE MM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyy
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MM-yyyy
```

What are your suggestions to solve this issue ?? 
Please feel free to ask for question edits to help clarify the question

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and either `Instant`or `OffsetDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is your expected outcome? In the first example I suppose you want the date chooser set to August 4, but what then in the case where the DB shell shows `2019-08-06T23:40:04.022Z` and `.toString()` in Java `Sun Aug 07 01:40:04 EET 2019`? Also what is your datatype in MongoDB? And would you be able to change it if it solves your issue?

Comment: I didn’t get why you think you need to parse the date. Neither did I get how your code could throw an exception *and* print `Tue Oct 15 10:20:56 SGT 2015`.

Comment: Well when i tried to do a simpleDateformat(" dd-MM-yyyy") and poassed for example ("22-03-2019") then setdate it actually works.

Comment: ok look,  that is  my code

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("22-03-2019");
System.out.println(date1); //Prints Fri Mar 22 00:00:00 EET 2019 exactly in my compiler 
jDateChooser1.setDate(date1);

Comment: but when i change the format and pass instead the output of mongodb which is "checkin_date" : ISODate("2019-08-04T17:40:04.022Z")," exactly in the database it throws the error unparsable  date Sun Aug 04 19:40:04 EET 2019 ... don't focus on exact dates just focus on the format,,  i wrote by mistake the comment from the code i got online

Comment: I may be confused in copying dates but the overall format is still correct

Comment: But you shouldn’t fetch date and time as a *string* from the database. Use a proper datetime object. When I don’t kow the MongoDB datatype, I can’t be sure which class, I am thinking perhaps `OffsetDateTime`. Are you using a JDBC `ResultSet`? Then perhaps something like `OffsetDateTime dateTime = yourResultSet.getObject(7, OffsetDateTime.class);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are using some library you've not explained, `jdatechooser`, to produce a `java.util.Date` which is being stored somewhere along your tool chain as a string `2019-08-04T17:40:04.022Z` and in another part of your toolchain is being represented by the string `Sun Aug 04 19:40:04 EET 2019`.

Let's tear those pieces apart.

We cannot help you with `jdatechooser` until you name the library, and preferably link to its product site.

The `java.util.Date` class is terrible, and is now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Never use it. This class, along with `SimpleDateFormat` & `Calendar`, were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Specifically, `Date` was replaced by [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert to-and-fro by calling new conversion methods added to the old class.

The string `2019-08-04T17:40:04.022Z` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-08-04T17:40:04.022Z" ) ;
```

Generating.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Yields: 2019-08-04T17:40:04.022Z
```

The string `Sun Aug 04 19:40:04 EET 2019` is in a terrible format. It assumes English, is difficult to parse by machine, fails to include all info (the fractional second is missing), and uses a pseudo-time-zone `EET` rather than a true time zone such as `Africa/Cairo`. Never use this format. Unfortunately, this is the format used by the `java.util.Date::toString` method. Even worse, that `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone to adjust the value that is actually in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), creating much confusion. Again, never use `Date` class for this and many other reasons.

You should focus on using `Instant` whenever you can in your code. This class represents a moment in UTC.

When using [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), your [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) may not support `Instant`. If not, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Comment: The link to `JDateChoser` is in [the tag description for the jdatechooser tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jdatechooser/info) given on the question (so admitted, more than one click away).